# Too many positional arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following class:

```
class AppState {
  final List<Exercise> exercises;
  final List<Answer> answers;
  final int currentQuestion;
  final bool isLoading;

  AppState({this.exercises, this.answers, this.currentQuestion = -1, this.isLoading = false});

  factory AppState.loading() => AppState(exercises: new List(), this.answers: new List(), currentQuestion: -1, isLoading: true);
}
```

I'm getting the following error in the `factory` line `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.`.

What is wrong with the class?

Comment: remove `curly braces` on AppState class

Comment: Replace `this.answers` by just `answers` in the `AppState.loading()` constructor